# Windows shows wrong size information of the external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

Hard drive shows only 139/931 GB is available
[image]
But this shows only 598 GB is consumed. Where did the rest go?
[image]

I have also selected hidden files so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with my internal SSD once (256gb), it told me I had 200mb free space despite the data on the drive only taking up ~140gb. This seems to be a problem with the way Windows handles files.

I fixed this by migrating my user profile, failing, and having to move everything back. I had to change a few registry values, so you could try running C-Cleaner or a similar reg-clean tool and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: don't use profanity on the site